# How to prevent override of member variables set inside of a static method in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having an issue where the variable in my class, which is set in a static method of the class; is constantly overridden by other calls of the method.

**For better understanding** this script is used to create a Texture on the fly which is only 1 pixel in width and height. **In usage** this texture can then be "stretched" over an area. However the texture cannot be saved. which is fine.

```
public class DrawPixelTexture
{
    private static Texture2D t1 = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.RGBA32, true);

    static DrawPixelTexture()
    {
        t1.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
    }

    public static void Texture(Rect rect, Color colour, float opacity = 1)
    {
        colour.a = opacity;

        // ensure that we only call Apply() once by reading the colour of the pixel at 0,0
        // and seeing id it is the same as 'colour'
        if (t1.GetPixel(0, 0) != colour)
        {
            Debug.Log("still being overriden");

            t1.SetPixel(0, 0, colour);
            t1.Apply();
        }

        Graphics.DrawTexture(rect, t1);
    }
}
```

here is  a usage example

```
public class TestDrawTexture
{
    void OnGUI()
    {
        DrawPixelTexture.Texture(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 20), Color.gray);
        DrawPixelTexture.Texture(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 20), Color.blue);
    }
}
```

"still being overriden" will be printed out constantly because the gray colour which was set is then overriden by the blue colour and vice-versa

how do I go about fixing this ?

Comment: By using a `static Texture2D t1`, you have just *one* for the entire app. Are you sure you *want*/*need* `static` instead of an instance value?

Comment: Never use statics for any reason in Unity - you can't.  it's an ECS system.  It's completely meaningless to have **a static in a component**.  This is an absolute basic of Unity engineering.

Comment: Thaks for the feedback. I am scripting an editor window so I can get away wit using a few static variables here and there.  :)

Comment: what, the heck, are you using "DrawTexture" for ?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating a cache where you store the texture for each colour you already used.

```cs
public class DrawPixelTexture
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Color, Texture2D> texturesCache = new Dictionary<Color, Texture2D>();

    public static void ClearCache()
    {
        texturesCache.Clear();
    }

    public static void Texture(Rect rect, Color colour, float opacity = 1)
    {
        colour.a = opacity;

        Texture2D texture;

        if (!texturesCache.TryGetValue(colour, out texture))
        {
            Debug.Log("still being created");

            texture = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.RGBA32, true);
            texture.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
            texture.SetPixel(0, 0, colour);
            texture.Apply();

            texturesCache.Add(colour, texture);
        }

        Graphics.DrawTexture(rect, texture);
    }
}
```

Comment: This not only made the process much more efficient but also showed me a way to fix many other similar problems in my scripts .
Awesome , Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

This is doing exactly what `static` is supposed to do which is to only have on instance of it. **Remove** the `static` from your functions and variables and then create 2 instance of `DrawPixelTexture`. One for `gray` and one for `blue`.

Note that you should not be using the OnGUI function. To display a UI, use, the `Image` or `RawImage` components then assign texture to them. If this is just a 2D Sprite then use `SpriteRenderer`. **Don't** use `OnGUI`.

`DrawPixelTexture` script:

```
public class DrawPixelTexture
{
    private Texture2D t1 = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.RGBA32, true);

    public DrawPixelTexture()
    {
        t1.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
    }

    public void txture(Rect rect, Color colour, float opacity = 1)
    {
        colour.a = opacity;

        // ensure that we only  call Apply() once by reading the colour of the pixel at 0,0 and seeing id it is the same as 'colour'
        if (t1.GetPixel(0, 0) != colour)
        {
            Debug.Log("still being overriden");
            t1.SetPixel(0, 0, colour);
            t1.Apply();
        }
        Graphics.DrawTexture(rect, t1);
    }
}
```

`TestDrawTexture` script:

```
public class TestDrawTexture : MonoBehaviour
{
    DrawPixelTexture gray;
    DrawPixelTexture blue;
    bool firstRun;

    // Use this for initialization
    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (firstRun)
        {
            gray = new DrawPixelTexture();
            blue = new DrawPixelTexture();
            firstRun = false;
        }

        gray.txture(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 20), Color.gray);

        blue.txture(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 20), Color.blue);

    }
}
```

Comment: I spent some time implementing both solutions and this does make the process more efficient however the next answer made it even more efficient. Though I do end up with some garbage . which is fine
I am using OnGUI because i am scripting an editor window :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: @DMDev "**I am using OnGUI because i am scripting an editor window**" That makes sense. It would be good to put in your question that the code is for Editor use. You go with what works best for you. Happy coding!

Comment: By the way @Programmer !  If you like pls vote here https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/eliminate-unityscript-totally-and-forever to remove U/S from Unity6!  That would be cool!

Comment: @JoeBlow I hate all the UNITYSCRIPT questions here. I just did. I think they will remove it but not now. They are slowly making the transition and don't want many people to get pissed off. The transition started when the video tutorials became C# only. Also, they will release the latest .NET C# for Unity soon. That' s probably when they will pull the plug.